# Use of tag calculus and multivariable calculus

Tags: discussion, tagging

When there is a tag of [multivariable-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multivariable-calculus) separately in math.stackexchange.com . Use of [calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus) as tag must not be added or a tag of single variable calculus must be added.

Comment: Please make your question more clear.

Comment: I think the OP means to ask something like what follows. Take an arbitrary question and assume (multivariable-calculus) is one of its tags. Pick the correct answer: i) (calculus) tag should be added; ii) (calculus) tag should not be added.

Answer (score 9):

I see two possible questions here.

Q1: Why have tags [calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus) and [multivariable-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multivariable-calculus) instead of [single-variable-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-variable-calculus) and [multivariable-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multivariable-calculus)?

A1: When students take a single-variable calculus course, they do not think of it as single-variable calculus. It is just calculus to them. Only later they may (or may not) get the appreciation of the multivariable calculus as a somewhat different subject. Depending on whether they do that, they will tag questions as [calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus) or as [multivariable-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multivariable-calculus).

Q2: If a question is tagged [multivariable-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multivariable-calculus), should it also be tagged  [calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus)?

A2: It can be, but this is not necessary. Most [multivariable-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multivariable-calculus) are not tagged [calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus) (we have $4509$ questions with multivariable tag only, versus $1211$ with both tags). Given the large number of [multivariable-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multivariable-calculus) questions, one can be reasonably confident that users interested in following this tag have added it to their favorites, along with (or instead of )  [calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus).